# Chicken Scheme and command line arguments

Tags: scheme

I am writing a program in Scheme which needs to examine the command line arguments. I figure a good way to get an executable is to use Chicken Scheme to compile the thing, but then I am running into problems:

Here are the contents of test.sch

```
(display (command-line))
```

I am invoking the compiler like so:

```
csc -require-extension r5rs test.sch
```

Which gives the following warning:

```
Warning: extension `r5rs' is currently not installed
```

but proceeds to generate an executable `test`. That executable, when run,

```
 $ ./test 

Error: (require) cannot load extension: r5rs

    Call history:

    ##sys#require       <--
```

Is `r5rs` an extension? I don't think so, since `chicken-install` doesn't seem to know about it:

```
 $ chicken-install r5rs

Error: unrecognized file-information - possibly corrupt transmission: "(error \"no such extension or version\" \"r5rs\" #f)"
```

I think I need to import `r5rs` to get the procedures `(display)` and `(command-line)`. But I cannot figure that out. I'd appreciate if someone can explain what I need to do to these two procedures bound so that

- I can examine the command line arguments
- I can print to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments are not a part of the R5RS or any other of the Scheme reports. Every implementation that supports a method has their own way and Chicken uses the built in parameter [`command-line-arguments`](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Parameters):

```
$ echo '(display (command-line-arguments))' > test.scm
$ csc test.scm
$ ./test 1 2 3
(1 2 3)
```

Edit: The [`(command-line-arguments)`](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Using%20the%20interpreter#writing-scheme-scripts) documentation has since been updated for Chicken 5, which you can view in documentation under [Using the interpreter](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Using%20the%20interpreter#writing-scheme-scripts).